# What is causing the value of this pointer to change from a simple function call?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, visual-c++, dll

A couple pictures are worth a couple thousand words in this case, so I will start with a description of what I am observing.  Here is my first exhibit which I will refer to as "stack frame 1":

[image: stack frame 1]

Here I am passing in a parameter of type `FLValue` (which is a typedef to a pointer to a C++ type that is internal to the DLL that defines the function being called) to a function called `FLValue_AsString`.  The value of the parameter at this point is 0x0486d10e.

Now note my second exhibit which I will call "stack frame 2":

[image: stack frame 2]

This stack frame is immediately above stack frame 1, and is the result of entering the function `FLValue_AsString`.  The debugger stepped immediately in and did not take any inlined side routes as far as I can tell (this was run with optimizations all disabled).  However, strangely, note that the value of `v` (the above `FLValue`) is now 0xedcf6fc2.  This obviously results in a crash due to invalid memory access.  What in the world just happened?

Some other information:

- The compiler is set to compile functions as `__cdecl` in all projects in the solution
- The function in question is defined inside an `extern "C"` block
- LiteCore.dll (the DLL which exposes `FLValue_AsString`) does not compile files directly, but rather is sort of a conglomerate which links together three static libraries and two other dlls, and defines a definition file of exposed symbols and so the function is actually defined inside of one of the static libraries inside.
- This is not the only place that I observe this behavior, although the majority of calls function normally
- If I manually change the memory address in the debugger to the one from stack frame 1, then I can continue without the invalid memory access
- When compiled with Apple Clang on OS X, or GCC on Ubuntu, none of these problems are observed

**EDIT** Some information in text form from the screen shots:

Trace @ stack frame 1 (starting at main()):

```
C4Tests.exe!PerfTest::insertDocs(const _FLArray * docs) Line 141    C++
C4Tests.exe!`anonymous namespace'::____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____491::test() Line 501 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::NWayMethodTestCase<`anonymous namespace'::____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____491>::invoke() Line 29 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::TestCase::invoke() Line 7519 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::invokeActiveTestCase() Line 6159 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::runCurrentTest(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & redirectedCout, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & redirectedCerr) Line 6131   C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::runTest(const Catch::TestCase & testCase) Line 5951  C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::runTests(const Catch::Ptr<Catch::Config> & config) Line 6297 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::Session::run() Line 6405 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::Session::run(int argc, const char * const * const argv) Line 6384    C++
C4Tests.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 10333    C++
```

Value of parameter being passed into `FLValue_AsString()`:

> foo   0x0486d10e {_byte=0x0486d10e "FRem... } const fleece::Value *

Trace @ stack frame 2:

```
LiteCore.dll!FLValue_AsString(const fleece::Value * v) Line 56  C++
C4Tests.exe!PerfTest::insertDocs(const _FLArray * docs) Line 141    C++
C4Tests.exe!`anonymous namespace'::____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____491::test() Line 501 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::NWayMethodTestCase<`anonymous namespace'::____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____491>::invoke() Line 29 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::TestCase::invoke() Line 7519 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::invokeActiveTestCase() Line 6159 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::runCurrentTest(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & redirectedCout, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & redirectedCerr) Line 6131   C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::RunContext::runTest(const Catch::TestCase & testCase) Line 5951  C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::runTests(const Catch::Ptr<Catch::Config> & config) Line 6297 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::Session::run() Line 6405 C++
C4Tests.exe!Catch::Session::run(int argc, const char * const * const argv) Line 6384    C++
C4Tests.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 10333    C++
C4Tests.exe!invoke_main() Line 64   C++
```

Value of parameter received by `FLValue_AsString()`:

> v 0xedcf6fc2 {_byte=0xedcf6fc2  }    const fleece::Value *

**EDIT 2**: Another weird piece of information is that in 64-bit builds the debugger shows the memory as 0xcccccccccccccccc when actually the memory is fine and the program continues without problem.

**EDIT 3**: Compiler options:

C4Tests.exe:

> /GS /TP /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Fd"C4Tests.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "DEBUG" /D "C4DB_THREADSAFE" /D "SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION" /D "C4_TESTS" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"C4Tests.dir\Debug\" /Fp"C4Tests.dir\Debug\C4Tests.pch"

LiteCore.dll:

> /GS /TP /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Fd"LiteCore.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "DEBUG" /D "C4DB_THREADSAFE" /D "SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "LiteCore_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"LiteCore.dir\Debug\" /Fp"LiteCore.dir\Debug\LiteCore.pch"

FleeceStatic:

> /GS /TP /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Fd"FleeceStatic.dir\Debug\FleeceStatic.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "DEBUG" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"FleeceStatic.dir\Debug\" /Fp"FleeceStatic.dir\Debug\FleeceStatic.pch"

Linking Options:

C4Tests.exe:

> /OUT:"D:\Development\couchbase-lite-core\build_cmake\C\tests\Debug\C4Tests.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/Development/couchbase-lite-core/build_cmake/C/tests/Debug/C4Tests.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "....\Debug\LiteCore.lib" "....\vendor\SQLiteCpp\sqlite3\Debug\sqlite3.lib" "....\vendor\forestdb\Debug\forestdb.lib" "......\vendor\openssl\libs\windows\x86\libeay32.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/Development/couchbase-lite-core/build_cmake/C/tests/Debug/C4Tests.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\Development\couchbase-lite-core\build_cmake\C\tests\Debug\C4Tests.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"C4Tests.dir\Debug\C4Tests.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

LiteCore.dll:

> /OUT:"D:\Development\couchbase-lite-core\build_cmake\Debug\LiteCore.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/Development/couchbase-lite-core/build_cmake/Debug/LiteCore.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "Debug\LiteCoreStatic.lib" "vendor\fleece\Debug\FleeceStatic.lib" "vendor\sqlite3-unicodesn\Debug\SQLite3_UnicodeSN.lib" "vendor\SQLiteCpp\sqlite3\Debug\sqlite3.lib" "vendor\forestdb\Debug\forestdb.lib" "Ws2_32.lib" "..\vendor\openssl\libs\windows\x86\libeay32.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/Development/couchbase-lite-core/build_cmake/Debug/LiteCore.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\Development\couchbase-lite-core\build_cmake\Debug\LiteCore.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"LiteCore.dir\Debug\LiteCore.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

FleeceStatic:

> /OUT:"D:\Development\couchbase-lite-core\build_cmake\vendor\fleece\Debug\FleeceStatic.lib" /NOLOGO

**EDIT 4**: Let's dive down even further into the emitted assembly.  Starting right before the call the `FLValue_ToString()`:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1B4h] // move foo's address into eax
push        eax
call        _FLValue_AsString (0144AC9Eh) 
jmp         dword ptr [__imp__FLValue_AsString (014BD208h)]
jmp         FLValue_AsString (0187DE00h) 
push        ebp
mov         ebp,esp
sub         esp,18h  
mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax // this should be v (the passed value ?)
mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax 
cmp         dword ptr [v],0   // v == ebp+0Ch
je          FLValue_AsString+34h (0187DE34h) // no jump here
lea         eax,[ebp-0Ch] // eax is overwritten with a pointer to 0xcccccccc
push        eax 
mov         ecx,dword ptr [v] // at this point v is garbage
call        fleece::Value::asString (016E4DE5h)  
jmp         fleece::Value::asString (01882DB0h) 
...
mov         dword ptr [this],eax  
mov         dword ptr [this],ecx // Why the double move here?  Both are invalid anyway...
```

So I guess this looks to be messed up calling conventions after all?  It seems like a misuse of ecx instead of eax?

**RESPONSE TO QUERY ABOUT FLSLICE**:
Externally it is defined like this:

`typedef struct {
    const void *buf;
    size_t size;
} FLSlice;`

internally in the static library it is typedef'd to a struct with the same member variables, with the addition of some methods that are used for internal operations as seen [here](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/fleece/blob/55c756a1bc2b89ddd89ccdfc01cd657691abd1fa/Fleece/slice.hh#L47).

Comment: Itty bitty screenshots are not helpful. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I would expect someone with your rep to know this by now....

Comment: Are you viewing this on mobile?  The screenshots are far from itty bitty (they are 1080p if you click through).  I'll work on the second part though.

Comment: Sorry, behind an evil work proxy. Can't click on them.

Comment: SO cannot search/index screen shots. Please use text.

Comment: You can copy/paste both the source and stack trace.  Which is faster than clipping the images to the relevant parts.  What compiler options are you using?

Comment: I will put in text for the relevant stack frames but I will leave the images because they show the relation between the stack frames and the variables there.

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch between the header file and the code in the DLL.

Comment: Could be a calling convention mismatch.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The calling convention on every project is set to __cdecl

Comment: @MarkRansom Wouldn't that cause problems on other platforms besides Windows?

Comment: May there be some implicit conversion? What happens if you replace `auto foo =` with `FLValue foo =`? (p.s.: we can only try to guess...)

Comment: @A.S.H I tried that as well with the same result.

Comment: and FLValue is a typedef to a *native* C++ pointer, not some kind of a smart pointer?

Comment: Yet anther guess, if you are on a multi-threaded app, a bug may come from another thread that corrupts the memory location...

Comment: @A.S.H. yes, I pasted one of the values into an edit, and the type is `const fleece::Value *`.  This test is done entirely on a single thread.  I'm not entirely sure I trust what the debugger is telling me anymore, because in 64-bit builds it shows 0xcccccccccccccccc as the memory address getting passed but there is no more invalid memory access exception and the test passes.

Comment: The debugger could be displaying a garbage value because the stack frame hasn't been set up yet.  Does the program actually crash, and what happens if you step another instruction or two into the function?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think you are onto something with that first one.  The program refuses to continue after that exception has been hit, but debugging in assembly mode shows that there is a whole lot of things happening in that one call (including some calls to `__imp__FLValue_AsString` which I guess is the translation from DLL to static lib?).  I will keep looking into that avenue.

Comment: *It seems like a misuse of ecx instead of eax* - I don't think so; I'm not sure where you're getting that idea from?  The function isn't using the initial values of either ecx or eax, which makes sense, since _cdecl doesn't use registers to pass arguments.  (The internal call to `fleece::Value::asString` appears to be using ecx to pass the `this` pointer, but that's OK, since internal calls don't have to follow call conventions.)

Comment: `foo` is being placed as the first argument, `ebp + 0x8` but is being read from the non-existent second argument, `ebp + 0xC`.  I think you need to check for a declaration/definition mismatch of some sort.  The missing argument might be the return value?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't follow where you see `ebp + 0x8`.  I'm terrible with assembly so forgive me for my ignorance.  It looks to me like the value is getting stored in `eax` so that the callee can retrieve it from there, only to have the callee attempt to read from `ebp` instead.  I don't see anywhere that correctly sets the `ebp` value.

Comment: No, `ebp` is the frame pointer, set by the `mov  ebp,esp` command.  It's the `push eax` command that puts the argument on the stack for the callee to read.  The first argument is always at `ebp+0x8` (four bytes of return address, four bytes to save the original value of `ebp`) but according to your comment, `v == ebp+0Ch` which the caller hasn't initialized.

Comment: What is the `FLSlice` type?  I'm not sure it is legal for an extern "C" function to return a non-POD type.  (PS: I'm not sure it isn't, either.  Just a thought.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I added a description of the `FLSlice` type to the end.  Come to think of it, the other place I remember this happening also makes use of this struct so this may be a common denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on Visual C++ calling conventions, but I strongly suspect that the difference in the declaration of `FLSlice` between the two modules has resulted in the caller expecting the return value to be passed by register and the callee expecting it to be passed in memory.  That results in a disagreement over which of the arguments represents the pointer in question.

From [X86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) on Wikipedia:

> There are some variations in the interpretation of cdecl, particularly in how to return values. [...] Some compilers return simple data structures with a length of 2 registers or less in the register pair EAX:EDX, and larger structures and class objects requiring special treatment by the exception handler (e.g., a defined constructor, destructor, or assignment) are returned in memory. To pass "in memory", the caller allocates memory and passes a pointer to it as a hidden first parameter; the callee populates the memory and returns the pointer, popping the hidden pointer when returning.

Note in particular that the presence of a constructor can affect the calling convention.

Comment: You, sir, are indeed an expert because that fixed it and also explained why it works on x64!  I rigged up a quick spike to convert back and forth between the two conversions instead of typedef and I saw the assembly change to ebp + 8!